# PostgreSQL check one of two fields

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have table well with name, code, and code2 fields.
How to write check to allow only rows with name and one of code present present?

```
WellA, null, Code2 -  OK
WellB, Code1, null - OK
WellC, Code3, Code4 - OK
WellD, null, null - NOT OK
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ADD CONSTRAINT my_check CHECK (COALESCE(Code1,Code2) IS NOT NULL);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ba31dd532d8ece30c92d30537d707f0e)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a check constraint:

```
CHECK (name IS NOT NULL AND
      (code IS NOT NULL OR code2 IS NOT NULL))
```